# Circle div in CSS doesn't show in canvas properly

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas 0.5.0 alpha1 and I added some circles to the div that I want to send to the canvas with this CSS:
    .circle {height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius: 20px; position: absolute; top: -8px;}

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/297705/8c3f811182dc5a909c9c1cbd270dabd2
looks like this on chrome/safari, the circle doesn't render well.

Works well on Firefox though.
Anyone knows of a way to fix the circle appearance on the canvas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `border-radius` must be the half of the width/height. So setting it to `10px` – or even better `50%` will render a smooth circle:

```
div {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmjqLz3p/

Comment: 50% doesn't work, renders a square, I tried 10px and it was a bit squared still, but with 12.5px it rendered reasonably well. This is the result http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/299460/e0c2697a1c3971c96596688e10031739 . In the canvas it is not as smooth as in the HTML, so I wonder if there's a html2canvas way of improving it, if nothing comes up for that I will mark this as correct.